# Automatically go to a Class in eclipse from Instance

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to automatically go to a Class in eclipse from an instance of it.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
// lots of lines of code
foo.some();   // from foo I want to go to the Class Foo direcly with a key press.
```

I received some answers but that is not what I was looking for. Sometime I don't call a method, I just have reference `foo` only, e.g when calling other method :

```
method(foo, bar);
```

Comment: Regarding the edit - I doubt you can do that, considering that what type of object a variable holds is determined at runtime

Comment: @froadie - It is perfectly possible, intellij does it very well with `Ctrl-Shift-B`

Comment: interesting. Let's say you have a declaration like `Parent a = new Child()`. Which class would it jump to?

Comment: @froadie - It would only go to compile time class.

Answer (score 9):

Hold down control and click on the class name.

You can also go to specific methods from method calls by using the "Open Declaration" functionality. So hold down control and click on `some()` and it will take you to that method's declaration in the Foo class. (Or hit F3, or right-click and choose "Open Declaration.")

Or you can use the constructor in the line: `Foo foo = new Foo();` to jump to the class' constructor, which will also take you to the class.

Comment: In my environment (Eclipse PDT), this does not work (any more). At the beginning, it worked fine. But suddenly, I cannot open the declaration (neither by pressing F3 nor by ctrl-clicking). What can be wrong? The only addon is Aptana, but jumping to the declaration also worked with aptana.

Answer (score 1):

You can ctrl-click on the variable name and you get to the variable declaration. And then you can ctrl-click on the type to get to the class definition.